# Error 1046 and 1119

Tags: actionscript-3, class, import, package, mouseevent

Hi there I'm having 2 errors which I can't seem to solve. Though it seems like it shouldn't be too much of a problem.

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip; //line 3
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class video01 extends MovieClip {


    public function video01() {
        // constructor code
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        trace("movieclip 1 geladen");

        btn_terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK.terug); //line 16


    }


    public function terug(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("knop ingedrukt");

    }


}
```

}

The errors are:
Line 3  1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: btn_terug.
Line 16 1119: Access of possibly undefined property terug through a reference with static type String.

Any thoughts?

---

*EDIT*

This is my main code, it resides on the timeline of the .fla:

```
import fl.video.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stop();

btn_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel1);
btn_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel2);
btn_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel3);
btn_4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel4);
btn_5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel5);
btn_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel6);
btn_7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel7);
btn_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel8);
btn_9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,speel9);


var mc_video01:MovieClip = new video01();
var mc_video02:MovieClip = new video02();
var mc_video03:MovieClip = new video03();
var mc_video04:MovieClip = new video04();
var mc_video05:MovieClip = new video05();
var mc_video06:MovieClip = new video06();
var mc_video07:MovieClip = new video07();
var mc_video08:MovieClip = new video08();
var mc_video09:MovieClip = new video09();

var filmAan = false;

function speel1(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video01);
    mc_video01.x=340; 
    mc_video01.y=227;
    mc_video01.width=1360;
    mc_video01.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel2(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video02);
    mc_video02.x=340; 
    mc_video02.y=227;
    mc_video02.width=1360;
    mc_video02.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel3(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video03);
    mc_video03.x=340; 
    mc_video03.y=227;
    mc_video03.width=1360;
    mc_video03.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel4(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video04);
    mc_video04.x=340; 
    mc_video04.y=227;
    mc_video04.width=1360;
    mc_video04.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel5(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video05);
    mc_video05.x=340; 
    mc_video05.y=227;
    mc_video05.width=1360;
    mc_video05.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel6(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video06);
    mc_video06.x=340; 
    mc_video06.y=227;
    mc_video06.width=1360;
    mc_video06.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel7(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video07);
    mc_video07.x=340; 
    mc_video07.y=227;
    mc_video07.width=1360;
    mc_video07.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel8(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video08);
    mc_video08.x=340; 
    mc_video08.y=227;
    mc_video08.width=1360;
    mc_video08.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
function speel9(evtObj:MouseEvent):void {
trace("knop 1: video 1");
    if (filmAan == false) {

    addChild(mc_video09);
    mc_video09.x=340; 
    mc_video09.y=227;
    mc_video09.width=1360;
    mc_video09.height=1060;

    filmAan = true;
}
}
```

The main page has 9 buttons that open a movieclip with a video, and button to go back to the main page. 
Each movieclip has a class named video01, video02 etc. (As seen above) The main .fla it's class is titled 'main'.

The buttons on the main page work, and all open a different movieclip(with the button inside). What I want to do is so that the btn_terug removes the child. But I'm getting error 1046 on line 3.

Hope this clarifies my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Phew, you're all over the place on this one, lol..so all import statements live after `package`..besides you have `import flash.event.MouseEvent` twice. It should not live in the constructor code. Second, your event listener should be like this:

`btn_terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, terug);`

not 
`btn_terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK.terug);`

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class video01 extends MovieClip
    {
        public function video01()
        {
            trace("movieclip 1 geladen");
            btn_terug.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, terug);
        }

        public function terug(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace("knop ingedrukt");
        }
    }
}
```

See how pretty that code is now? =)

Comment: Haha I sure made a mess of that code :], thanks for replying. I still have the same error on line 3 though: 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: btn_terug. 
Any suggestions? Thx for the help

Comment: Is this your document class? How are you instantiating this class?

Comment: The document class is the 'main' AS file am I right? I have put the main code on the timeline in the .fla, not in a seperated .as file. Ill edit my question and put some more details in there. And sorry, what do you exactly mean with: 'how are you instantiating this class?'